# Test for Generated Class From WSDL

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, soap, wsdl

Should I write unit test for those apex classes generated from wsdl when deploying to production?

Comment: It will automatically get covered through the test class written for the out bound logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will count for coverage, so it's best to have unit tests that cover them. Always strive for close to 100% coverage.

My experience is that you may need some special tests just for coverage, as the functional unit tests may not cover all of the WSDL's parts. But these tests are typically not difficult to write.

Of course, I don't know how big your WSDL is.

Comment: It was quite a big class. :) But eventually I handled somehow.